# Sum of values from 3rd previous month

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate, date-arithmetic, aggregate-filter

I'm having difficulty grabbing rows from December (anything from the **3rd previous month**). I'm attempting to count the amount of products sold within a certain time period. This is my current query:

```
 SELECT
   a.id,
   a.default_code,
(
   SELECT SUM(product_uom_qty) 
   AS 
   "Total Sold" 
   FROM 
   sale_order_line c 
   WHERE 
   c.product_id = a.id
),
(
   SELECT SUM(product_uom_qty) 
   AS 
   "Month 3" 
   FROM sale_order_line c 
   WHERE
   c.product_id = a.id
   AND 
   MONTH(c.create_date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '3 Months')
   AND
   YEAR(c.create_date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '3 Months')
)
FROM
   product_product a
```

This is what the DB looks like:

**`sale_order_line`**

```
product_id product_uom_qty  create_date
33         230              2014-07-01 16:47:45.294313
```

**`product_product`**

```
id  default_code 
33  WHDXEB33
```

Here's the error I'm receiving:

> ```
> ERROR:  function month(timestamp without time zone) does not exist
> LINE 21:    MONTH(c.create_date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL
> ```

Any help pointing me in the right direction?

Comment: What is the problem with your query?

Comment: Hi Lennart. Sorry about that, I've added the error above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**date_trunc()**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) to calculate timestamp bounds:

```
SELECT id, default_code
    , (SELECT SUM(product_uom_qty)
        FROM   sale_order_line c 
        WHERE  c.product_id = a.id
       ) AS "Total Sold" 
    , (SELECT SUM(product_uom_qty)
        FROM   sale_order_line c 
        WHERE  c.product_id = a.id
        AND    c.create_date >= date_trunc('month', now()) - interval '2 month'
        AND    c.create_date <  date_trunc('month', now()) - interval '1 month'
      ) AS "Month 3"
FROM   product_product a;
```

To get December (now being February), use these expressions:

```
    AND    c.create_date >= date_trunc('month', now()) - interval '2 month'
    AND    c.create_date <  date_trunc('month', now()) - interval '1 month'
```

`date_trunc('month', now())` yields '2015-02-01 00:00', after subtracting 2 months, you get '2014-12-01 00:00'. So, "3 months" can be deceiving.

Also, be sure to use [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) expressions like demonstrated for faster performance and to allow index usage.

#### Alternatives

Depending on your actual DB design and data distribution, this may be faster:

```
SELECT a.id, a.default_code, c."Total Sold", c."Month 3"
FROM   product_product a
LEFT  JOIN (
   SELECT product_id AS id
        , SUM(product_uom_qty) AS "Total Sold"
        , SUM(CASE WHEN c.create_date >= date_trunc('month', now()) - interval '2 month'
                   AND  c.create_date <  date_trunc('month', now()) - interval '1 month'
              THEN product_uom_qty ELSE 0 END) AS "Month 3" 
   FROM   sale_order_line
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) c USING (id);
```

Since you are selecting all rows, this is probably faster than correlated subqueries. While being at it, aggregate *before* you join, that's cheaper, yet.
When selecting a single or few products, this may actually be *slower*, though! Compare:

- [Aggregate a single column in query with many columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16018237/aggregate-a-single-column-in-query-with-many-columns/16023336#16023336)
- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest record per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-record-per-user/25536748#25536748)

Or with the `FILTER` clause in Postgres **9.4+**:

```
...
        , SUM(product_uom_qty) 
             FILTER (WHERE c.create_date >= date_trunc('month', now()) - interval '2 month'
                     AND   c.create_date <  date_trunc('month', now()) - interval '1 month'
                    ) AS "Month 3"
...
```

Details:

- [Select multiple row values into single row with multi-table clauses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28444148/select-multiple-row-values-into-single-row-with-multi-table-clauses/28454774#28454774)

Answer (score 2):

This will avoid the costly correlated subquery

```
select
    pp.id, pp.default_code,
    sum(sol.product_uom_qty) as "Total Sold",
    sum((
        date_trunc('month', pp.create_date) =
        date_trunc('month', current_date) - interval '3 months'
        )::int * sol.product_uom_qty
    ) as "Month 3"
from
    product_product pp
    left join
    sale_order_line sol on pp.id = sol.product_id
group by 1, 2
```

The cast from `boolean` to `integer` results in 0 or 1 which is convenient to be multiplied by the value to be summed